# When I trade Cryptocurrency for Cryptocurrency without cashing out how does taxation apply?

Tags: united-states, taxes, cryptocurrency

I'm assuming (Crypto to Crypto) is tax free until it's converted to fiat.

Comment: "Why does trading shares in Apple for shares in Tesla cause a taxable event?" - Because those are two different assets. Just like ETH and BTC are different assets.

Comment: This question kind of reminds me of https://xkcd.com/1494/ for a reason I can't quite articulate.

Comment: Note that this is really important because a lot of "crypto", **isn't**. For example I could imagine folks trying to exchange back and forth to Tether and whining that they shouldn't have to pay taxes.

Comment: Is, is that how currency trading works? "This one weird trick will have Forex traders fuming!"

Comment: In tax terms, you can trade one cryptocurrency for another without cashing out on exactly the same terms as if you were trading hard currency. How does that not work for you?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin crypto is not covered by Sec. 988. The IRS treats crypto as an asset, not a currency. Forex trades are considered contracts and are covered by Sec. 1256, also not relevant here since crypto purchases are not contracts but exchange of assets. Not sure what comparison you're making.

Comment: @littleadv Jolly good. Why not explain exactly what difference that will make on your own tax return? Seriously, at the level of A+/-B
=C.

Exactly how is I bought/sold this asset different from I bought/sold this currency?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin well... Sec 988 is one such example :)

Comment: Why do you assume that? When it comes to the IRS, I generally believe it's safer to assume something *is not tax free*, especially if investing is involved.

Comment: @littleadv In 988 foreign currency gain is treated as ordinary income but the point is whether your accountant can convince the IRS that whatever currency went and remains off-shore.

A secondary point is whether OP is trading one cryptocurrency for another, which might make a profit, or really trading Cryptocurrency for Cryptocurrency which seems pointless.

I think US laws say citizens can't have "offshore" assets but that pretends "offshore" means "held elsewhere" when in fact it means out of reach of the government.

Try telling Apple or Amazon anything offshore is taxable!

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Apple or Amazon have multiple entities, a lot of inter-company chargers and accounting tricks. Rich individuals can try some of that through similarly set up shell corporations, but for "normal" people it's just cost prohibitive.

Comment: @littleadv Thanks and that's way, way off topic. The real Question remains, how do cryptocurrencies relate to your dollar.

My suggestion remains that the only real of cryptocurrencies is that they're offshore in the real sense.

Does that not work for you?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin not really seeing that. It's just an asset, how is it different than bonds or stocks?

Comment: @littleadv Sorry: I slipped into arguing against myself with "how is I bought/sold this asset different from I bought/sold this currency?" Of course it is, which is prolly why your IRS wants cryptos to be assets.

Still isn't the point of cryptos that they're genuinely off-shore, which means the taxman can't count them until, as Almight first Asked, they're converted back to fiat money?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I have no idea what the point of cryptos is, other than being a pyramid scam. But you're arguing that a taxman shouldn't be taxing them because you don't want them to be taxed - that's a bit silly IMHO. The IRS most certainly taxes offshore transactions.

Comment: @littleadv You're missing the meaning of "off-shore" holdings. In reality, the Mafia designed off-shore banking to put profits beyond IRS view, as it still does. No see; no tax.

The popular sense of "off-shore" as you or I having cash in Albanian, French or whatever foreign accounts and it's still taxable, is simply misguided, at best.

How could cryptos being pyramid scams change their tax status? I say nothing about "should"; merely that a large part of the point of cryptos is that since they're supposed to be truly off-shore items, being assets or currencies can't matter.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I understand what offshore means, but "no see;no tax" is not what the law says. You're saying that what the IRS doesn't know about isn't taxable, but it's not true. There's a reason for all the lawsuits and criminal proceedings against the Swiss banks, the FATCA requirements, etc. Having cash in a offshore account isn't taxable, what's taxable is income and it doesn't matter where the asset generating income is or where the US tax resident is in the world when they generate that income.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I didn't understand what you're trying to say, you seem  to have copied my comment into yours inadvertently. But if your point is that by mere hiding assets you're making the income untaxable - there's a name to it, it's called *tax evasion* and it is generally a crime.

Comment: @littleadv Sorry; no-one can claim to understand what "off-shore"means who denies "no see; no tax".

What the IRS doesn't know about isn't taxable. How could it be otherwise, or can you explain how IRS can tax what it can't see!

Of course what's taxable is income. Of course it doesn't matter where the tax-payer is in the world when that income is generated… nor are those relevant.

Cash in offshore accounts isn't taxable because it's not visible to on-shore authorities. That's what off-shore means… 

Some might see that as evasion and I suggest, most people won't

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin this is a ridiculously naive view of the world. Your "What the IRS doesn't know about isn't taxable" claim is laughable. The US tax law is based on self-reporting, the IRS doesn't see a lot of things which are nonetheless taxable. As I said - what you're describing is called *tax evasion* and is a crime. It doesn't matter how *you* see it, what matters is how *the law* sees it.

Comment: @littleadv Sorry. We all know Al Capone got it wrong and still, his buddy Myer Lansky invented off-shore banking specifically to stop the IRS viewing their dealings. Do you doubt that? What matters isn't how you or I view it, but that the law can't see it. Can you not see the difference?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin you do realize that that's exactly what brought Al Capone down, right?

Comment: Absolutely not. As I said, "Al Capone got it wrong." Had he paid more attention to Lansky, he'd have got away with much of the tax stuff, as well as everything else. Even if you were Meyer Lansky, would you have liked to tell Al Capone to pay attention?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From The Motley Fool's web article, "[How is Cryptocurrency Taxed?](https://www.fool.com/investing/stock-market/market-sectors/financials/cryptocurrency-stocks/crypto-taxes/)":

> A crypto trade is a taxable event. If you trade one cryptocurrency for another, you're required to report any gains in U.S. dollars on your tax return.
>
> Every time you trade cryptocurrencies, you need to keep track of how much you gained or lost in U.S. dollars.

So even if you never convert it to dollars, you will owe on the gains.

**And from the horse's (IRS') mouth, [question #16 on their virtual currency FAQ webpage](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/frequently-asked-questions-on-virtual-currency-transactions) says:**

> Q: *Will I recognize a gain or loss if I exchange my virtual currency for other property?*
>
> A. If you exchange virtual currency held as a capital asset for other property, including for goods or for another virtual currency, you will recognize a capital gain or loss.  For more information on capital gains and capital losses, see [Publication 544, Sales and Other Dispositions of Assets](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-publication-544).

Comment: In addition, here is a very detailed guide on how to handle your Crypto taxes: https://cryptotrader.tax/blog/the-traders-guide-to-cryptocurrency-taxes There are different methods of accounting to consider and differences if it is a trade vs a staking reward or airdrop.

Comment: does that mean forex is taxable?

Comment: @FamousJameis Yes, under either [section 1256](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1256) or [section 988](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/988). But cryptocurrency transactions are just taxed the same way other dispositions of capital assets are taxed. (With forex, the foreign currency is usually not actually held as a capital asset and thus there isn't a disposal of a capital asset other than the forex contract itself.)

Answer (score 22):

Your assumption is incorrect.

When you trade cryptocurrency for a different cryptocurrency, it is a taxable event that triggers a capital gain (or loss). Essentially, it is treated as if you had sold the first cryptocurrency for dollars, and then purchased the second cryptocurrency with dollars.

This is consistent with the capital gain rules for any other asset. If you trade one stock for another stock, or if you trade goods with another person in a barter transaction, you still potentially have a capital gain on the asset you got rid of based on the market value of it at the time of the transaction, and you have established a new cost basis of the asset you obtained.

Answer (score 0):

Totally depends on the country you are taxable in.

Keep all records of all transactions (timestamp, value, if possible fiat/crypto exchange rate (buy+sell) at the given time). Taxes are most likely to be accounted for in Fiat.

In Switzerland for example, this is not a taxable event and **you can deduct the Exchange's fee as asset management expenses from the income**. Property tax is due on the Fiat equivalent at end of fiscal year. Switzerland is one of the rare countries where stock/currency exchange gains are not subject to income tax.

Comment: Hey, @stonux. The Stack is strict on the scope of the question. This one is tagged [tag:uinited-states] so answers should focus on that particular country. Nothing against adding more information, but you didn't mention USA.

Comment: anyway, sometimes it profits everyone when an anwers *enlarges* the original question. Good answer.